# Chain dependent bash commands

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, command-line

I'm trying to chain together two commands:

- The first in which I start up postgres
- The second in which I run a command meant for postgres(a benchmark, in this case)

As far as I know, the '||', ';', and '&/&&' operators all require that the first command terminate or exit somehow. This isn't the case with a server that's been started, so I'm not sure how to proceed. I can't run the two completely in parallel, as the server has to be started.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something along the lines of the following in a single *bash* script:

1. Start the *Postgres* server via a command like `/etc/init.d/postgresql start` or similar
2. Sleep for a period of time to give the server time to startup; perhaps a minute or two
3. Then run a `psql` command that connects to the server to test its up-ness
4. Tie that command together with your benchmark via `&&`, so it completes only if the `psql` command completes (depending on the exact return codes from `psql`, you may need to inspect the output from the command instead of the return code). The command run via `psql` would best be a simple query that connects to the server and returns a simple value that can be cross-checked.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

It depends on what you want to benchmark. If you just want to benchmark a command after the server has started, and don't want to restart the server every time, then I would tweak the code to run the `psql` up-ness test in a separate block, starting the server if not up, and then afterward, run the benchmark test command unconditionally.

If you do want to start the server up fresh each time (to test cold-start performance, or similar), then I would add another command after the benchmarked command to shutdown the server, and then sleep, re-running the test command to check for up-ness (where this time no up-ness is expected).

In other case you should be able to run the script multiple times.

**A slight aside:** If your test is *destructive* (that is, it writes to the DB), you may want to consider dumping a "clean" copy of the DB -- that is, the DB in its pre-test state -- and then creating a fresh DB, with a different name from the original, using that dump with each run of the script, dropping it beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify, I want to start the server and run the benchmark as a single command(and do this multiple times). Would this solution require the server to be started via a different command?